# The picture I draw is invisible after I reset the width and height of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In the js file:

```
function main_part2() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("viewport");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var eye = new Vector(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);

    raycasting(context, eye, PART2);
}
function change_size() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("viewport");
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    main_part2();
}
```

In the html file:

```
<body onload="main_part2();">
<canvas id="viewport" width="512" height="512" style="background-color: black"></canvas><br><br>
<label for="width">Width: </label><input id="width" type="number"><br><br>
<label for="height">Height: </label><input id="height" type="number"><br><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="change_size()">Change</button>
```

I try to reset the width and height of the canvas through two inputs and draw a new picture according to the new canvas. However, when I click the button, the canvas get resized, but raycasting function, which will draw a picture, makes no effect. How could I make it work?

Comment: Could anybody help me

Comment: Changing the size of the canvas resets it, that includes all pixels (effectively clearing it). Either resize before adding the image, or store the image and redraw it after each resize.

Comment: I did the first way. I resize by using canvas.width = width;canvas.height = height; And then draw using main_part2(). But the image does not appear.

Comment: Actually there is a image. But it is mostly hidden by the canvas.